# How to obtain the q-factorial from Bhargava's factorial?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, q-analogs

For certain nice rings, Bhargava constructs a generalized factorial via p-orderings; the details of which can be found in [Bhargava](https://www.math.upenn.edu/~ted/620F09/Notes/Bhargava/2695734.pdf). In example 18, of section 10, he states that the generalized factorial on the p-ordered set 
$\left\{\frac{q^n-1}{q-1}\right\}_{n \in\mathbb{N}} \subset \mathbb{C[q,q^{-1}]}$ recovers the q-factorial $\prod_{i=1}^n\frac{q^i-1}{q-1}$. When I use the method, I obtain $\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{q^n-q^k}{q-1}=q^{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}}\prod_{i=1}^{n}\frac{q^i-1}{q-1}.$

- Can someone explain why he does not have the *extra* factor of
  $q^{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}}$?

Perhaps, I didn't follow his procedure correctly..

Comment: M. Bhargava. The factorial function and generalizations. Amer.Math. Monthly 107 (2000), 783–799

Comment: @JeanMarie Yes, that is the article that I intended to link. Thanks.

Comment: @Chris I've added an answer, but I'm not sure this was your question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$q$ in invertible in $\mathbb C[q,q^{-1}]$. Bhargava's factorial are defined as generators of the factorial ideals. These generators are defined up to an invertible.

Comment: Yes, great. I wasn't thinking of his factorial as being a generator.. Relieves a big headache for me, thanks.